# iOS:convert decimal into 2 byte hex format

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, decimal, arrays

I have decimal value 48 i need to convert it to the 2 hex byte format .the i have written code as below

```
            int a=48;
```

in a value 48 is there and in need  to fill 48 in 2 bytes

```
     fill data[0]=/*converted data*/
     fill data[1]=/*converted dara*/
```

Please help with the sample code as i am new to objective c  coding.converted data contains data in the format ex:0x03,0x04 like that 
how can i fill the data.Please help me

Comment: can u give me reason for  down vote or u did not understand the quoestion

Comment: What is `fill` in the code you posted? Provide more details about what conversion you are looking for. Your question is very confusing and unclear.

Comment: you fell victim to the stack overflow police...  or JERKS as I like to call them. Don't take it personally, your just probably not as smart as they are...  none of us are. That said, your question is weak in context, and I agree with rmaddy, what is fill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2-byte hex format... huh ?!

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but perhaps this'll help:

```
int a = 48;
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", a];     //  "30"

int byte1 = [str characterAtIndex:0];       // 51  (ASCII code for '3')
int byte2 = [str characterAtIndex:1];       // 48  (ASCII code for '0')
```

This returns two bytes, representing the ASCII characters that make up the hex number "30".

If you actually wanted the bytes to contain the values 3 and 0, then it's even easier:

```
int a = 48;
int byte1 = a / 16;       // 3
int byte2 = a % 16;       // 0
```

Similarly, if you wanted that 48 value converted into 0x0030, and byte1 is set to 0x00 and byte2 is set to 0x30, then simply do this:

```
int a = 48;
int byte1 = a % 256;       // 48
int byte2 = a / 256;       // 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: 48 in decimal format should be fitted in 2 bytes .is it possible

Comment: Errr, what does that MEAN ?
Doesn't my last example, to store 48 in byte1 and byte2 meet this criteria ?